# How to change text color from red to white?

Tags: materials, node-editor, text-object, color

I did a text animation based on this YouTube video.

[Dissolve Animation by Tutor4u](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q93pE5jB1Uw)

When I render by clicking the animation button I get this.

[APG Dissolve Animation](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-r582QxjMQMRzlrSDEzNjQ2Ync/view?usp=sharing)

My issue is I want to color the "A" and "P" text white (hex color - ffffff) and leave the "G" text red (hex color - ff0000) but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Here is my blend file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to top view (Numpad7) In edit mode select the A & P text with box select. In the material tab add new color and change color white (fffff) and assign the material to the mesh.

[image]

Comment: The "A" and "P" will not stay white when I press the animation button.